# DbReferenceEntry.IsLoaded always returns false for a navigation property even after Lazy Loading or Explicit Loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a Navigation property which is already loaded into the DbContext (Verified using SQL Profiler, and Visual Studio debug Intellisense shows the full proxy object loaded for the navigation property).
However calling [DbReferenceEntry.IsLoaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbreferenceentry.isloaded(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbReferenceEntry.IsLoaded) on the reference always returns `false`.
I thought [DbReferenceEntry.IsLoaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbreferenceentry.isloaded(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbReferenceEntry.IsLoaded) is guaranteed to always return `true` when the object is loaded into memory. The situation doesn't change even after an explicit call to [DbReferenceEntry.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbreferenceentry.load(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbReferenceEntry.Load) on the reference.
I also realised [DbEntityEntry.State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.state(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry.State) for the object was in the `Modified` state and I'm wondering if this is why the `IsLoaded` is `false`.

Accessing the navigation property however does not make any *lazy loading* call to the db (Verified with SQL Profiler) which is an indication the local copy is indeed accessible.

**My Question is:** Is [DbReferenceEntry.IsLoaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbreferenceentry.isloaded(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbReferenceEntry.IsLoaded) for an Entity dependent on the state of the Entity (e.g. `State.Modified`)? Though I cannot find any documentation that seems to suggest this.

---

### EDIT:

I run tests which seems to indicate the `IsLoaded` property is not affected by the `Modified` state.

**My Question is:** What are the conditions that will cause the `IsLoaded` property to return `false` even though the related property is already loaded into the context?